# Error non-fast-forward al intentar subir nuevos archivos a git

Tags: git, github

estoy tratando de subir un proyecto modificado a github, he realizado:

```
git add * 
git commit -m "comentario"
git push origin master
```

Al realizar esto ultimo me aparecia:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch)
```

Por lo tanto he decidido hacer git fetch, al volver a repetir los pasos anteriores me sale el siguiente error y ya no consigo subir mi proyecto.

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/nombreproyecto
```

A que se debe este error y como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias!!

Comment: `git fetch` no modifica tu rama local. Solo trae los commits remotos y los deja en una copia local de la rama remota, pero que no es master, sino origin/master. Hasta que no hagas `git merge` no se aplican esos commits a la rama local. Puedes hacer simplemente `git pull` que hace la secuencia `git fetch` + `git merge`.

Comment: vale es decir hago git pull y a continuación repito git add * y todo eso ? o ya directmente hago git push origin master ?

Comment: Al hacer pull en teoría git debería mezclar los commits que te vienen del remoto con los commit que tienes en local, y si todo va bien, crear un nuevo commit de merge. Puedes ver en el log local que ese commit sea el más reciente una vez finalice el pull. En ese momento puedes hacer push y el remoto debería aceptarlo. No obstante el merge puede fallar si tu rama local contiene  cambios incompatibles con la rama remota. En ese caso debes resolver los conflictos manualmente, añadir con `git add` los conflictos ya resueltos, y hacer un `git commit` para completar el merge.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu repuesta, y he conseguido fusionar las ramas y ya tengo el proyecto subido :)